# how to convert the pptx file to pdf file in php in live site

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to convert pptx file to PDF using :

```
$powerpnt = new COM('powerpoint.application') or die('Unable to load PowerPoint');
```

but the above function is not working in live site give some solution for that problems.

Comment: Read this http://blog.muhimbi.com/2013/02/converting-files-to-pdf-and-other.html

Answer (score 0):

**pedamorf** is a server that converts documents, images, urls, html and text to PDF. It relies heavily upon the excellent open-source programs wkhtml2pdf, Libre Office and iTextSharp. A client library is provided and **can be used from a .NET application** to utilize the conversion services provided by pedamorf.
this is the [source](https://github.com/bradyholt/pedamorf) of the library.

I hope that help you!